# How do I show only language specific and translated taxonomy terms in a field which references a taxonomy?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

How do I show only language specific and translated taxonomy terms in a field which references a taxonomy?

In my xyz content type I have taxonomy reference fields. While translating the content created using "xyz" content type, I would like to show only language specific taxonomy terms (either translated or created in that specific language).

How can I achieve this?

As suggested by Clive I have created a entity reference view which shows only languages specific and translated terms. Here is the screen shot of the same.
[image]

But when I link that view from product category field which is of type entity reference it shows taxonomy terms in default language i.e. English in my case instead of Spanish Language but the terms are filtered as per language i.e. Spanish.
Here is the screen shot of the same.
[image]

Can somebody please suggest if I am missing a step here ?

Comment: That's the behaviour I see out of the box - what are you seeing instead?

Comment: I see all the taxonomy terms translated as well as not translated ones.For example if I have four values a,b,c,d and a is translated I see a-spanish,b,c,d.

Comment: Oh right, yes you'll see any terms you haven't translated in their original language. I suppose you could use a View as the source for the entity reference field and filter out the untranslated terms that way

Comment: Clive are you suggesting to use entitybrowser or inlineentityform which can work on a custom view ? Actually I didn't want to take that approach because I am currently using chosen module and it's formatters

Comment: No - core allows you to choose a View with a specific display to drive the data for an entity reference field. It won't affect the form widget you're using, just provide you with filtered data

Comment: Hi Clive , thanks for your suggestion. I was not aware of that option. I will give it a go.

Comment: Hi Clive, I tried to create a specific view and attached it to my field . It works well independently but within my node it shows filtered terms but in default language always instead of showing translated terms. Can you please provide any insights into this ? I have updated the question with some screenshots to provide some more details.